# Narrow categories in Default Extended Multi Reference Editor in Backoffice to subcategories of a given category

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to filter the supercategories that can be referenced by a given product in Hybris Backoffice. For example if we have the following category structure:

### CategoryA

SubCategoryA1
SubCategoryA2

### CategoryB

SubCategoryB1
SubCategoryB2

Lets say I want my products to be able to reference only subcategories of CategoryB. In the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1905/en-US/8bab997f86691014852cfbeabd21a5c8.html) is given an example how to narrow the results and guarantee that all search results would have the same catalog version as the parent-object with a relation to the current editor.

```
<editorArea:attribute qualifier="supercategories">
    <editorArea:editor-parameter>
        <editorArea:name>referenceSearchCondition_catalogVersion</editorArea:name>
        <editorArea:value>{parentObject.catalogVersion}</editorArea:value>
    </editorArea:editor-parameter>
</editorArea:attribute>
```

What changes should I make in the configuration?
I guess I need to somehow restrict the available categories to be a subtype of a given supercategory.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `restrictToType` to filter by the specific type:

```
<wz:property qualifier="item">
                        <wz:editor-parameter>
                            <wz:name>restrictToType</wz:name>
                            <wz:value>Product</wz:value>
                        </wz:editor-parameter>
 </wz:property>
```